# Stop triggering another event receiver from first event receiver

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, event-receivers, timer-jobs

am writing an timer job in SP 2013 on-prem version to manipulate some list items .But there exists already an item event receiver to update some other manipulations .
 i wanna  prevent triggering that event receiver when i do this list update from y custom time rjob.
 how to achieve this functionality?

```
           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            { 
              using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteurl))
              {
                 using (SPWeb paramObjspWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                 {
                    try
                    {
                        paramObjspWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList riltlist = 
                   paramObjspWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Tracker");
                        SPListItem singleitem = riltlist.GetItemById(205);
                        Console.WriteLine(" ID is +++++ " + 
                      singleitem["ID"].ToString());

                     Console.WriteLine(" SI NO is +++++ " + 
                    singleitem["Sl.No."].ToString());

                        Console.WriteLine("project code is +++++ " + 
             singleitem["Project Code"].ToString());
                        singleitem["Project Code"] = " NPR_ELE_DUPS_011_17";
                        singleitem.SystemUpdate();
                    }                           catch { }
                   }                }            });
```

// here in this line `singleitem.SystemUpdate();`  it automatically triggering the  other item event receiver which i wanna  stop.

Answer (score 2):

When we are in List Item Event Receiver code, we can modify/update the same item which will fire the event receiver again. For disabling event receiver to get fired again use [Disable event firing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.disableeventfiring.aspx) while updating item. And then enable event firing again after update item.

Create your own Event receiver handling class as follow.

```
public class EventReceiverManager : SPEventReceiverBase, IDisposable
{
    public EventReceiverManager(bool disableImmediately)
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = !disableImmediately;
    }

    public void StopEventReceiver()
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }
    public void StartEventReceiver()
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

And use this class as below.

```
using (var eventReceiverManager = new EventReceiverManager(true))
{
    var list = GetList("listName");
    var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    listItem["field"] = "value";
    listItem.Update();
}
```

---

**What happens when Event Receiver disabled?**

When you disable event receiver, SharePoint internally set a data field in current Thread. So if you can set your current’s thread’s data to the required value before/after updating item, you can control the event receiver. However, setting current thread data manually might be risky. So we can use ‘SPEventReceiverBase’ to control event receiver firing.